# NPM Error: EPERM: operation not permitted. Tarball data for <package> seems to be corrupted

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I've been trying to create a new angular app with the cli, but I keep getting this error.

At first I thought it was something related to the version of cli I had installed( the latest one), so I uninstalled it and tried with the same version(`6.0.8`) that is used in the course I'm following along, but I get the same error :

[image: error image]

Do you have any idea how I can figure out what is causing this issue?
Is there any log I can check?

I'm using :

```
Node: v8.11.3    
Npm: 6.4.1    
Windows 10 Pro.
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using this command:

```
npm install --registry https://registry.cnpmjs.org
```